# How to use reCAPTCHA in a web service?

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, recaptcha-enterprise

Our Android app interacts with our back-end service via REST APIs. Both, the front-end as well as the back-end, are Java based.

We need to add reCAPTCHA during login. The idea is to prevent fraud if the back-end API is called directly from some batch script.

All the examples using Google reCAPTCHA seems to be around displaying the image in a web page. In our case, we wish to display it in our native Android app, perhaps along with the username/password fields.

I am thinking the front-end may need to make two calls to the back-end. The first call to obtain either the image as binary data or an URL to the image. The second call would pass in the authentication parameters along with the reCAPCHA value entered by the user.

Wondering if someone can point me in the right direction. Thinking this is a common scenario for many of us.